# Filter url pattern conflict in web.xml ?

Tags: caching, jakarta-ee, html, ehcache, web.xml

I am working on a projec, the  application is in j2ee and I have used ehcache for web page caching but due to the entries of filter it gives me an error content encoding error i have added following filter and ehcache.xml can anyone say which entry causes it ?

web.xml filter entry

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
    <filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>Set the size limit for uploaded files.
                   Format: 10 - 10 bytes
                  10k - 10 KB
        </description>
        <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
        <param-value>100m</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>Set the threshold size - files below this limit are stored
             in memory, files above this limit are stored on disk.
                     Format: 10 - 10 bytes
                     10k - 10 KB
        </description>
        <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>100k</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadRepositoryPath</param-name>
        <param-value>/home</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>extensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>CachePage1CachingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.SimplePageCachingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>suppressStackTraces</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cacheName</param-name>
        <param-value>CachePage1CachingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CachePage1CachingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

ehcache.xml is as follow

```
 <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="10"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="5"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10"
    overflowToDisk="true"
/>
<!-- Page and Page Fragment Caches -->
<cache name="CachePage1CachingFilter"
    maxElementsInMemory="10"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="10000"
    timeToLiveSeconds="10000"
    overflowToDisk="true">
</cache>
```

Edited:-

I tried and i got the problem is because of the url pattern in

```
   <filter-name>CachePage1CachingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

in filter it goes continuously in filter the exception was reentrant exception if i am write following

```
    <filter-name>CachePage1CachingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
```

it works fine but i want it to be worked for jsf and entry of jsf is done in preety config like follow

```
 <url-mapping id="ManageUsers">
    <pattern>/manageUsers</pattern>
    <view-id>/pages/master/manageUsers.jsf</view-id>
 </url-mapping>
```

what should i do to avoid this ?

Comment: It helps if you post the exact error message including stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the servlet spec 2.5 (implemented by Tomcat 6) you can specify multiple url patterns:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CachePage1CachingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

For prior to 2.5, you'd be able to specify two mappings

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CachePage1CachingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CachePage1CachingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```